# Why is the calculation from my code giving me different answers from calculators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using Python 3.6.0. I noticed that the output from my code and giving answers different from calculators and I could not find out why.

```
L = [5,5,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i] *= 1000

for i in range(len(L)):
    if i == 0:
        L[i] = int(L[i]*0.6+L[i+1]*0.2)

    if i < (len(L)-1) and i != 0:
        L[i] = int(L[i-1]*0.2+L[i]*0.6+L[i+1]*0.2)

print(L)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[4000, 4200, 2640, 3128, 4025, 5000]
```

However, there seems to be calculation problem when i is above 0. For example:

> When i is 2, L[2] = int(L[1]*0.2+L[2]*0.6+L[3]*0.2) = 2800

but the output from the program is 2640. Where is the source of error?

I would greatly appreciate if anybody can assist me with this.

Comment: Why are you expecting that... you're asking for `4200*0.2 + 2000*0.6 + 3000*0.2` which is 2640... ? You've changed L[1] from being 5000 to 4200 in your previous loop... and you're mutating the values in your list on every loop... either that's deliberate or you want to be building a new list and not touching your existing list? To see what's happening put a `print(L)` at the top of your second for loop...

Comment: @JonClements Ohhh I get the problem now. I was trying to alter the list by changing the values of its element but I totally forgot the the changes stack loop after loop. It was not intentional. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're altering the array as you go through. That is, you're trying to calculate a new list from the old one - but because you're referring to values that you've already changed, it's interfering with the calculation.

If this is the issue, the fix is simple - just make a new list, say `M`, and replace `L` by `M`in everything but the formulas on the right-hand-side of the `=` signs.